# Численные методы. Метод итераций для двух уравнений

Tags: java, математика, численные-методы

Пытаюсь преобразовать уравнения x*cos(x)-y=0 и x^2+y^2-1=0 к итерационному виду. Из-за производной косинуса выходит очень неприятное уравнение, которое не сходиться. Хотя вроде бы у этой окружности и кривой есть 2 точки пересечения.
Помогите пожалуйста.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class МетодИтераций2уравнения {

    double x1, x2, e, d, bufX1, bufX2, y1, y2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        МетодИтераций2уравнения Zadacha4 = new МетодИтераций2уравнения();
        Zadacha4.Vvod();
        //Zadacha4.Proverka();
        Zadacha4.Start();

    }

    public void Vvod() {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = System.in;
            Reader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            System.out.println("Введите начальное значение Х1");
            x1 = Double.parseDouble(bufferedReader.readLine());
            System.out.println("Введите начальное значение Х2");
            x2 = Double.parseDouble(bufferedReader.readLine());
            System.out.println("Введите точность");
            e = Double.parseDouble(bufferedReader.readLine());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("-----Ошибка ввода");
            Vvod();
        }
    }

    public void Start() {
        int c = 0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                double F1 = x1*Math.cos(x1)-x2;
                double F2 = Math.pow(x1, 2)+Math.pow(x2, 2)-1;

                y1=x1+(1-(Math.sqrt(3))/3)*F1+(-1+(Math.sqrt(3))/3)*F2;
                y2=x2+(Math.sqrt(3)/Math.PI)*F1+(2*(Math.sqrt(3))/Math.PI*(1+Math.sqrt(3)))*F2;
                
                d = Math.max(Math.abs(y1 - x1), Math.abs(y2 - x2));

                /*d = Math.abs(y1 - x1);
                if (Math.abs(y2 - x2) > d) {
                    d = Math.abs(y2 - x2);
                }*/
                c += 1;
                print(c);
                if (Double.isNaN(d) || Double.isInfinite(d)) {
                    break;
                }
                if (d < e) {
                    break;
                }
                x1 = y1;
                x2 = y2;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Общих корней нет");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        //System.out.println("Программа завершена");
    }

    public void Proverka() {
        if (x1 > 0) {
            System.out.println("Условие х1 < 0 нарушено");
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }

    public void print(int c) {
        DecimalFormat dF = new DecimalFormat("#.######");
        System.out.println("\nИтерация (" + c + ")\nX1 = " + dF.format(y1)
                + "\nX2 = " + dF.format(y2)
                + "\nПогрешность измерения = " + dF.format(d));
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подставляя во второе уравнение, получаем

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так что формула для итераций —

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все. Находим x (два значения — плюс и минус), а по ним значения y.

Сами напишете? Я в Java не силен...

Ответ — `x = 0.82846` и `y = 0.56005` (ну, и те же значения с минусами)

Comment: Да сам напишу, без проблем. Спасибо.